# Add association to new record with existing model's ID

Tags: elixir, ecto

I have an M2M relationship established between a `users` table and a `plans` table. They're joined through a `users_plans` table.

When I create a new `plan`, I want to associate it to a `user`. I have that user's `ID`.

So I'm trying to create the association like so:

```
  def changeset(plans, attrs) do
    plans
    |> Repo.preload(:users)
    |> cast(attrs, [:details])
    |> put_assoc(:users, attrs[:users])
    |> validate_required([:details])
  end
```

`attrs` looks like: `{"details": "we're going to the mall today", "user_ids": [{"id": 1}]}`.

Anyway, all I get is an error message: `{"errors":{"users":["is invalid"]}}`. I believe this is because `put_assoc` expects me to provide a full `user` record. Is this something I should be doing?

Could someone explain how I can create the `plans` object and associate to the existing `user` with ID `1`?

EDIT:

I've changed the request body to:

```
{ 
  "details": "we're going to the mall today", 
  "user_ids": [1]
}
```

And I am querying for the users like so: `users = Repo.all(from(u in User, where: u.id in attrs[:users]))`, but I can't access the `users` key in `attrs`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I ended up going with. Open to other recommendations.

Input:

```
{ 
  "details": "lorem impsum", 
  "user_ids": [1]
}
```

`changeset` function:

```
  def changeset(plans, attrs) do
    users = Repo.all(from(u in User, where: u.id in ^attrs["user_ids"]))

    plans
    |> Repo.preload(:users)
    |> cast(attrs, [:details])
    |> put_assoc(:users, users)
    |> validate_required([:details])
  end
```